# How to use categorical_hinge loss in keras in order to train with an SVM in the last layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, svm, data-science

I wanna train a CNN using SVM to classify at the last layer. I understand that the categorical_hinge is the best loss function for that . I have 6 classes to classify .
My model is as shown below:

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(Conv2D(50, 3, 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(50, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(50, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(400, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Is there a problem with the network , data processing , or the loss function?

The model does not learn anything after a point as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBOIK.png)
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your model has a single output neuron, there is no way this will work with 6 classes. The output of your model should have 6 neurons. Also the output of your model should have no activation function in order to produce logits that the categorical hinge can use.

Note that the categorical hinge was added recently (2-3 weeks ago) so its quite new and probably not many people have tested it.

Comment: I removed the activation function and changed the target variables to categorical and trained the network and I don't think training is correct. The model hardly makes any improvement . the accuracy stays at 18-20% for 150 epochs . Is there anything wrong with the compilation function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hinge` loss in and `linear` activation in last layer.

```
model.add(Dense(nb_classes), W_regularizer=l2(0.01))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(loss='hinge',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

for more information visit https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6090